# In Autohotkey , how would I delete the .java part of my command line?

Tags: autohotkey

I am frequently using command-line to compile my java code .

And I often need to delete the whole `.class` or `.java` part. Thus , if the command line current shows :

```
MyTestClass.java
```

I want to use CTRL + Backspace to make it just:

```
MyTestClass
```

I have the following AHK script, but it only deletes up to theperiod.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
; Paste in command window
^V::
Send !{Space}ep
return

^BackSpace:: ;;Delete previous word
Send ^+{Left}
Loop, 500 {
    Send {Del}
}
Return

#IfWinActive
```

Comment: I can't find a solution for vanilla command line. I suggest installing [clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/), which adds many functions to the command line, as `Alt+Backspace` to delete words (and periods are considered being word delimiters).

Comment: @SalvoF your comment seems to be the answer to the problem, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest installing [clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/), which adds many functions to the command line, as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd> to delete words (and periods are considered being word delimiters).